# Is [self autorelease] acceptable?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, uikit

There are cases where you want to present an alert style view controller using your own animations (instead of using `presentModalViewController:animated:` or `UIAlertView`).

The right way of releasing this view controller would be in a callback called when the view disappears, but setting up a delegate and all that seems overkill.

So I do this:

```
- (void)dismiss
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
        self.view.alpha  = 0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self.view removeFromSuperview];
        [self autorelease];
    }];
}
```

and the presenting object would not release or autorelease the view controller. Memory management wise I see no issue with this. Is it bad practice?

Comment: you could `autorelease` the `self` (but I don't see the point) but the `removeFromSuperview` is enough for the `superview` to `release` the `self` object.

Comment: Are you sure? I think `removeFromSuperview:` would release the view, but not the view controller.

Comment: yes, you are right, it release the `view` only. some info for the memory management: you **should not** `release` or `autorelease`  any object which is not created or retained by you, it would cause memory leak. you must `release` or `autorelease` the objects which you `init`, `copy`, `retain` or `new`, otherwise it would cause memory leak. simple. :)

Comment: yes but I'm matching the retain count by autoreleasing self, self is dealloc'ed so there is no leak here.

Comment: if you don't `retain` the `self` inside the class (there is no reason why you would do that, you wouldn't? because the `self` won't be deallocated until any thread's run loop keeps the object alive, and I won't mention the other object whom keeps it alive with a `strong` pointer) you won't need to `release` or `autorelease` the `self` because you never `retain`'d before inside the object.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider this bad practice.

Only objects that have called `retain` on this object should call `release` or `autorelease` on it.

I do assume that you haven't called `[self retain]`

---

I'm not even sure this would work as you expect it to. Can you guarantee that `self` would need releasing at that point and why couldn't an object that has retained it called `release` itself?. Are you trying to force `self` to `dealloc`?

If `self` was deallocated at this point, any other object that was expecting `self` to still be alive would be passing messages to nil, or worse, the memory might be re-allocated and those objects would be sending messages to arbitrary objects.

Comment: "If you access an instance variable by reference, self is retained".  From here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html

Comment: I don't _need_ to release self this way, it's just more convenient because I wouldn't have to set up delegate/callbacks this way. The view controller takes care of itself.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like bad practice however don't see any effect on memory. In terms of modal view why don't you just pop it back if thats what you want to achieve using:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: I'm not using a navigation controller.